# slow typing due to Sys.Desktop.KeyDown and Sys.Desktop.KeyUp methods

Tags: windows, winapi, vbscript, testcomplete

We are using `Sys.Desktop.KeyDown` and `Sys.Desktop.KeyUp` VB methods of TestComplete to type into Notepad.

For this we are using a `for` loop containing `KeyDown` and `KeyUp`, however for some reason, even after the for loop ends, the typing is still not complete, its typing slowly, not sure why.

I checked by removing anti-virus software, but still seeing the issue. I have also tried to use the `Win32API.GetKeyState(Asc("A"))` however sometimes we get 1 and sometimes 0, so really need to debug this issue out. Could anybody suggest a way to debug this issue?

Comment: You are Doing It Wrong™. You want [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx)

Comment: When you see a program misbehave when you test it then you never look for the source of the problem in the testing tool.  The 99.99% odds are that the program is simply sluggish at processing input, assuming that you don't otherwise slam it at a highly unrealistic rate.  A very common bug, it probably has to be rewritten to move expensive code to a worker thread.  File a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use .Keys() on the main text area object?

Something like:

```
Set textObject = Sys.Process("notepad").Window("Notepad", "Untitled - Notepad", 1).Window("Edit", "", 1)
Call textObject.Keys("Hello")
```

This is my preferred way of sending text when it is directed toward a particular object. Please refer to this [link](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/55062/) for more information on the Keys method.